# Failed to load state: Remote workspace Terraform version X does not match local Terraform version X

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to do a force-unlock but TF complains about the version even though I'm using the same one.

```
terraform force-unlock -force UID
```

Results in:

```
Failed to load state: Remote workspace Terraform version "~>1.3.4" does not match local Terraform version "1.3.4"
```

```
➜ terraform --version
Terraform v1.3.4
on darwin_arm64
+ provider [...]
```

Terraform state is in AWS and the terraform version is managed by `tfenv`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see the error says, `Remote workspace Terraform version "~>1.3.4"`
Should verify if it's running the later of the minor, i.e., v1.3.9.

This can be confirmed in the tfstate. For example:

```
{
 "version": 4,
 "terraform_version": "1.4.6",
```